# Required Field Validation Error Message is working for Text Box but not working for Drop Down List

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my aspx page, I have 2 search options

One is for searching a product through text box.
Another is viewing category by drop down selection.

So this is what I have done in my .aspx file

```
<div class="searchbox">
        <strong>Search by Product Name<br /></strong> 
        <br />
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox> &nbsp;
        <asp:Button ID="Button8" runat="server" OnClick="Search_Product"  Text="Search Product" />
&nbsp;
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBox1" ErrorMessage="Please enter a product name"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        &nbsp;<asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server"></asp:Label>
        <br />
        <br />
        </div>

        <br />

        <div class="searchbox">
             <strong>View by Category: View Product on Category Selection</strong><br />
            <br />
            <asp:DropDownList AppendDataBoundItems ="true" ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="Product_Category_Name" DataValueField="Product_Category_Name">
                <asp:ListItem>Select a Category</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
             <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Grocery_DemoConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT Product_Category_Name FROM Product_Category"></asp:SqlDataSource>
&nbsp; 
            <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="DropDownList1" ErrorMessage="Please select a category"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            <br />
            <br />
            <asp:Button ID="Button9" runat="server"  OnClick="View_Product" CausesValidation="false" Text="View Product" />
            &nbsp;
            </div>
```

And this is what I have done in my .cs file

```
private void DisplayProducts()
        {
         if (Session["BranchAdmin"] != null)
            {
                string branch = Session["BranchAdmin"].ToString();
                string CS;
                CS = "data source=LAPTOP-ODS96MIK\\MSSQL2014; database = Grocery_Demo; integrated security=SSPI";
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS);
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("AdminViewProductsOnBranch", con);
                cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GroceryBranchName", branch);

                con.Open();
                GridView1.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                GridView1.DataBind();
                con.Close();
            }
        }

        protected void Search_Product(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Session["BranchAdmin"] != null)
            {
                string branch = Session["BranchAdmin"].ToString();
                string CS;
                CS = "data source=LAPTOP-ODS96MIK\\MSSQL2014; database = Grocery_Demo; integrated security=SSPI";
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS);
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("AdminSearchProductsOnBranch", con);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductName", TextBox1.Text + "%");
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GroceryBranchName", branch);
                cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                con.Open();
                GridView1.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                GridView1.DataBind();
                con.Close();

                con.Open();
                SqlDataReader read = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                read.Read();
                if (read.HasRows == false)
                {
                    Label3.Text = "Couldn't find your product";
                    con.Close();
                }
            }
        }

        protected void View_Product(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Session["BranchAdmin"] != null)
            {
                string branch = Session["BranchAdmin"].ToString();
                string CS;
                CS = "data source=LAPTOP-ODS96MIK\\MSSQL2014; database = Grocery_Demo; integrated security=SSPI";
                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS);
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("AdminViewCategoriesOnBranch", con);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProductCategoryName", DropDownList1.SelectedValue);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GroceryBranchName", branch);
                cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                con.Open();
                GridView1.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                GridView1.DataBind();
                con.Close();

                con.Open();
                SqlDataReader read = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                read.Read();
                con.Close();
            }
    }
```

If I search a Product in text box and click on the search button it shows the grid view display if it has the data in table. If the search result doesn't match with data in table, then it shows a Label Text Message: "Couldn't find your Product". And If I keep the text box blank and click on search button, it shows a required field validation message "Please enter a product name".
Everything is OK with product search option through text box.

On the other hand, when I select a category from drop down and click on view button, it works perfectly. 
Now the issues is if I don't select any category from drop down and click on view button, then it is not showing the required field validation error message "Please select a category"  and at the same time it is turning the grid view display into blank which I don't want.

What I'm trying to achieve is that if a category is not selected from drop down list and then a view button is clicked, it should show the required field validation error message "Please select a category" and at the same time it should not change the default Grid View display into blank.

If there is any mistake in the codes in either .aspx file or .cs, then it would be helpful if the recommended solution syntax is provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify `ValidationGroup` for TextBox1 required field validator and Search button controls like this:

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBox1" ValidationGroup="SearchByName" ErrorMessage="Please enter a product name"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

<asp:Button  ValidationGroup="SearchByName"  ID="Button8" runat="server" OnClick="Search_Product"  Text="Search Product" />
```

Specify a different `ValidationGroup` from dropdown validator and View_Product button

```
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="DropDownList1" ErrorMessage="Please select a category" ValidationGroup="SearchByCategory"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>

        <asp:Button ID="Button9" runat="server"  OnClick="View_Product" ValidationGroup="SearchByCategory"   Text="View Product" />
```

Note: I have removed the `CausesValidation="false"` attribute from View Product button.

Set the value of default list item as -1 and then specifying the InitialValue of dropdown validator?

```
<asp:ListItem value="-1">Select a Category</asp:ListItem> <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="DropDownList1" InitialValue="-1" ErrorMessage="Please select a category" ValidationGroup="SearchByCategory">
```

Comment: Do I also need to make any changes with <asp:RequiredFieldValidator> for DropDown ?

Comment: In fact you  just need to add `ValidationGroup="SearchByCategory"` property to Dropdown validator and not on the dropdown itself. Check the updated answer

Comment: I used your code ... The validation is working for the text box ... But the validation is not working for the Drop Down ... When I'm not selecting a category ... It is supposed to show validation message but it is not showing the validation message ... Instead it is turning the default grid view display into blank

Comment: Have you specified `ValidationGroup="SearchByCategory"` on both dropdown validator and View Products button? Also, ensure `CausesValidation="false"` is removed from the ViewProduct button. If it still does not work try this:
`<asp:ListItem value="-1">Select a Category</asp:ListItem>` `<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="DropDownList1" InitialValue="-1" ErrorMessage="Please select a category" ValidationGroup="SearchByCategory"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>`

Comment: Yes I have removed CausesValidation="false" and also added ValidationGroup="SearchByCategory" in both drop down validator and view products button: <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="DropDownList1" ValidationGroup="ViewByCategory" ErrorMessage="Please select a category"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>   AND <asp:Button ID="Button9" runat="server"  OnClick="View_Product" ValidationGroup="ViewByCategory" Text="View Product" />

Comment: Have you tried the second solution? Setting the value of default list item as -1 and then specifying the `InitialValue` of dropdown validator?
`<asp:ListItem value="-1">Select a Category</asp:ListItem> <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="DropDownList1" InitialValue="-1" ErrorMessage="Please select a category" ValidationGroup="SearchByCategory"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>`

Comment: Now I have added asp:ListItem value="-1">Select a Category</asp:ListItem>  and added InitialValue = "-1" under <asp:RequiredFieldValidator> ... Now it is working perfectly :)

Comment: Great! I have also updated the answer as well. If your issue is resolved you can accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator runat="server" ControlToValidate="DropDownList1"
cssclass="required" display="dynamic" errormessage="Please select a category" setfocusonerror="true"
initialvalue="0"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

Add `display="dynamic"`property.

Comment: I have used your code ... and when I click on view button, it is still not showing the required field validation error message and it is turning grid view display into blank.

Comment: You may also refer to the click event code portion: <asp:Button ID="Button9" runat="server"  OnClick="View_Product" CausesValidation="false" Text="View Product" />

Comment: Yes,  You can do as suggested by beginIT

Comment: This is what I did right now: <asp:Button ID="Button9" runat="server"  OnClick="View_Product" cssclass="required" display="dynamic" CausesValidation="false" Text="View Product" /> ... But it is still not showing the validation error message even if I don't select a category from drop down and it is still turning the grid view into blank.

Comment: If you refer back to my .aspx code, besides <asp:RequiredFieldValidator>,  Have I done any mistake in <asp:DropDownList> and <asp:SqlDataSource >